# How to generate a rotation matrix given an angular momentum matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, rotations, quantum-mechanics

In 3 dimensions, the total angular momentum (for $z$) matrix is given. It generates the rotation matrix around $z$ by $e^{-i\theta J_3/h}.$ My question is how do we actually go about doing this? I know that given the pauli matrices it would be $e^{-i\theta\sigma n/2}=\cos(\theta/2)I+i\sin(\theta/2)\sigma$ for a two dimensional rotation. But this method doesn't work for my aforementioned problem.

I.e. Where $J_z= I\hbar\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

I want to show that $e^{-I\theta J_3/\hbar}=\begin{pmatrix}cos(\theta)&-sin(\theta)&0\\sin(\theta)&cos(\theta)&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$

as I've seen it written in numerous texts but have no idea how it's obtained. I just want the method I don't need it worked out.

Comment: If there is an ambiguity I'm not aware of in my question let me know and I'll add more details

Comment: This appears to be more of a physics question than a mathematics one. You should perhaps consider posting this on [physics.SE]

Comment: @Brian theirs no underlying physics concept I'm asking about , It's a purely mathematical process, they don't like questions like that over there....

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what you mean by "the total angular momentum (for z) matrix" and "generates the rotation matrix around z"? This question seems to be about how a specific physical phenomenon may be modeled by a matrix rather than relating to matrices themselves. Forgive me if I am misunderstanding you question. Perhaps a MathJax examples of the matrices you are referring would help?

Comment: @Brian I edited my question with the details :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** We have
$$-\frac{I}{\hbar} J_z = \pmatrix{&-1\\1\\&&0},$$
so
$$\exp \left(-\frac{I}{\hbar} \theta J_z \right) = \exp \left[\theta \pmatrix{&-1\\1\\&&0} \right].$$
The standard procedure for computing an exponential matrix is to diagonalize (or more generally, decompose in Jordan normal form) the argument $A$ as $A = P D P^{-1}$ and then compute $$\exp A = P (\exp D) P^{-1} .$$ The eigenvalues of $\theta \pmatrix{&-1\\1\\&&0}$ are $\pm i \theta, 0$, so $$\exp D = \exp \pmatrix{i \theta\\&-i\theta\\&&0} = \pmatrix{\exp(i\theta)\\&\exp(-i\theta)\\&&1} .$$
All that remains is to compute the similarity matrix $P$, expand our expression for $\exp D$ using Euler's formula (namely, $\exp i\theta = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$), and compute $P (\exp D) P^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

To exponentiate a matrix $A$, find the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and eigenvectors $\xi_i$ of $A$. $e^A$ has the same eigenvectors $\xi_i$ as $A$, but with eigenvalues $e^{\lambda_i}$.

Equivalently, diagonalize $A$ by writing it as $A = P^{-1}DP$ for some diagonal matrix $D$. Then $e^A = P^{-1}e^DP$. For most applications in physics, $P$ will be a unitary matrix.